# Service Cloud Portal Home Page

Tags: customer-portal, force.com-sites

We want to use the High Volume Customer Portal License Portal for Login to Sites and have it directed to a custom page. I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to redirect from the portal log-in page to something other than the standard customer service portal.

I don't see anything in the portal set-up that allows this. I've looked at the login controller code and the VF code for it, but neither pointed me to where that url is stored. What am I missing in order to direct all users to a different landing page after a secure log-in?

Answer (score 2):

the startUrl parameter for SiteLoginController specifies the landing page when a user is successfully authenticated. You can change the value in the controller and redirect the user to the page of your choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had seen the variable in the controller, but didn't know if it was stored someplace in an object. Apparently not? If so, that's a simple one to handle, but was looking for confirmation that it wasn't stored elsewhere where it could be overwritten. Could I create a final static variable to hold the startURL value that gets returned by the controller?